# JTextArea keeps adding lines in for loop, how to prevent this?

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array, jtextarea, netbeans-6.9

I am currently working on a gradebook sort of program. The user enters the name of a student and the marks they got on 4 tests, which it then to a 2D Array. When I click the 'Student Average' Button to determine the average mark of said student, I want it to print the student info and then the average a line after. But the output right now, shown in the picture, adds around 15 extra lines before the average is displayed.

[image]

I'm not sure what is happening in my code that is causing this, but I will attach the actionPerformed code of the Student Averages Button. This code is where all the magic happens:

```
    private void studentAveragesButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    int sum = 0;
    int studentAverage = 0;

    studentName = lastNameInput.getText() + " " + firstNameInput.getText();

    for (int row = 0; row < studentMarks.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < studentMarks[0].length; col++) {
            if (studentMarks[row][col] != null) {
                studentMarkScreen.setText(studentMarkScreen.getText() + "   " + String.valueOf(studentMarks[row][col]));
                if (studentMarks[row][col].equals(studentName)) {
                    if (studentMarks[row][0].length() > 3) {
                        for (col = 1; col < studentMarks[0].length; col++) {
                            sum += Integer.parseInt(studentMarks[row][col]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    studentAverage = sum / 4;
    studentMarkScreen.append("\n");
    studentMarkScreen.append("The overall average for " + studentName + " is " + studentAverage + "%.");
```

}

Comment: I'd strongly recommend taking a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> studentName = lastNameInput.getText() + " " + firstNameInput.getText();
> ```

I would guess the variable `lastNameInput.getText()` has garbage.

You can easily test this by adding a :

```
System.out.println( "(" + lastNameInput.getText() + ")" );
```

Even if that isn't the problem you need to add debug code to display the value of the text area every time you set/append text to it. Then you can determine which statement is causing the problem.